# My Narrow component not working on Communities

Tags: community

My Narrow component not working on Communities . it give a  site under construction page.
Current iFrame in the home page widget VF is like the following:

```
<iframe  ="" src="/apex/HelloWorld?isdtp=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="200px" style="min-height:320px;max-height:400px;"  id="myFrame"  onload="sizeFrame('myFrame')" id="mmFrameId_0.050366452895104885"></iframe>
```

what is the solution to give the Relative url of my visual page? and
Is there anyway to find out if the user is in community or not using html/javascript in homepage component code.?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot give a relative URL in this fashion. To display VF pages by injecting via iframe in home page component you need to have to construct the URL in this way

`/communityPrefix/pageName`

Also other things to take care is, if you have any links in the VF pages where you have given the links like `/apex/pageName` will not work in community. You can make these dynamic by using the global variable `$site.prefix` also you can access the site prefix in apex code site.getPrefix() method in case you are using pagereference for routing the users to other VF pages in community.